# Only one textfield is dismissing for ios return key

Tags: ios, xcode, text

I have two fields, fldPassword and fldUsername. With this code (and a self delegate in the view did load), I would expect the return key to dismiss at both of the text fields. However, it only does it on the first. What am I doing wrong?

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {
    if (fldPassword == self->fldPassword) {
        [fldPassword resignFirstResponder];
    } else if (fldUsername == self->fldUsername) {
        [self->fldUsername becomeFirstResponder];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: You're not even using `theTextField`, you should compare this to fldPassword and/or fldUsername. If you always want to dismiss (I don't recommend this, breaks the flow). Then drop all that logic and just have [theTextField resignFirstResponder]; and return YES.

Comment: yes you are right, I will delete mine then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dismissing only the fist one, try this:

```
    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {
        if (fldPassword == self->fldPassword) {
            [fldPassword resignFirstResponder];
        }
        if (fldUsername == self->fldUsername) {
            [self->fldUsername resignFirstResponder];
        }

        return YES;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is exactly the same as my code (which isn't working)

Comment: Is not, I'm my code I'm calling resignFirstResponder in both textfields

Answer (score 2):

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {
        [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
   return YES;
}
```

in your .h file add delegate method :

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
```

then it will work for both textfields.

hope this helps u.